# I want to get the filename in a string from a directoy using c++

Tags: c++, linux, file

I have a directory called test. This directory is created dynamically while running another part of the code. And test contains different files. These files are also generated automatically. Suppose I have generated a1.txt,a2.txt,a.c,a3.txt,b.c in the directory test. I want to get the a3.txt file name in a variable. That means I want to iterate on the content of the directory and get the name of the ".txt" file associated with the largest number. Please help me regarding this issue.

Comment: Linux. Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

Using the opendir function,

```
DIR *opendir(const char *name);
```

After opening that directory, using the `readdir` get the files in that directory.

```
struct dirent *readdir(DIR *dirp);
```

Using the structure you can get the file name and You can use that file.

Answer (score 0):

The following gives you both directories and files in a given directory.

```
using namespace std;

int getDirContent (string dir, vector<string> &files) {
    DIR *dp;
    struct dirent *dirp;

    if ((dp  = opendir(dir.c_str())) == NULL) {
        cout << "Error(" << errno << ") opening " << dir << endl;
        return errno;
    }

    while ((dirp = readdir(dp)) != NULL) {
        files.push_back(string(dirp->d_name));
    }

    closedir(dp);
    return 0;
}

string dir = string(".");
vector<string> files = vector<string>();
getDirContent(dir,files);
```

Comment: While executing this I am getting "*** Error in `./a.out': double free or corruption (out): 0x00007ffff869f680 ***
Aborted (core dumped)" error! Compilation was successful.